# How can I quickly update cache expiration schedules for 100s of datasets?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssrs-2016

I have over 100 different datasets on an ssrs-2016 site. Each one of those datasets needs a new caching schedule. I have created a shared schedule to apply to each dataset, but I am wondering if there is a quick way to apply that schedule to each dataset without clicking through each one and adding the schedule.

Can this be done through DML against a report server database? If so, is it wise to run DML in a report server database?

Comment: check `[ReportServerTempDB].dbo.ExecutionCache` to see if it helps.